# Matlab 2019a "Invalid MATLAB toolbox project."

Tags: matlab, package, add-on

I have a Matlab toolbox that I've been working with for a few years. I have Matlab 2019a and 2017a installed currently. I can compile the toolbox with 2017a with

```
matlab.addons.toolbox.packageToolbox('toolbox.prj', 'output.mltbx')
```

When I run the same line in 2019a, I get the following error:

```
Invalid MATLAB toolbox project 'C:\Users\david\Documents\MATLAB\toolbox_dir\toolbox.prj'.
```

Is there some way to alter the current `toolbox.prj` file I have so that it will compile in 2019a? Or is there some way that I can see where the problem is in my `toolbox.prj` file? If I attempt to open the `.prj` file by double-clicking on it from within Matlab I get an error dialog that says "Not a valid project: toolbox.prj."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug with the solution being to update to Matlab 2019a Update 5.